# ios: How to make UIPickerView(UIView) catch touch event before UITouchRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

[Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW44) said "There may be times when you want a view to receive a touch before a gesture recognizer. ", but I couldn't find how to do that.

I tried delaysTouchesEnded = false, but it does not have any effect.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.pickerViewTapped(_:)))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    tapGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
    myPickerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    // called by UIPickerView 
    print("pickerView called!")
}

func pickerViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // called by UITapGestureRecognizer
    print("pickerViewTapped called!")
}
```

When I tap myPickerView, the console would be

```
pickerViewTapped called!
pickerView called!
```

But I want them in reverse order. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't do it using UIGestureRecognizer only.

**Long answer:**

There is always a delay between the action of select a row of a UIPickerView and the call of the method `didSelectRow`, due to the animation required for move the row to the center of UIPickerView itself.

Also note that if you tap of the row at center, you don't call the `didSelectRow` method, but `pickerViewTapped` only.

This delay necessarily make this sequence of the execution:

1. `pickerViewTapped`
2. `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
   didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){`

The solution I found is this:

```
func pickerViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // called by UITapGestureRecognizer

    let timeDelay = 0.6
    //0.6 is arbitrary value, depends on you
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeDelay) {
        print("pickerViewTapped called!")
    }
}
```

I know maybe it is not the answer you were looking for, neither I know why you would have such behaviour but this is the nearest solution I've found.